# How to boot directly into GUI without going through tty

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, tty, dnf

I recently did `dnf update` and it uninstalled gnome, so I did `dnf groupInstall "Fedora Workstation"`. This restored gnome but every time I boot up, I have to login from the console and use `startx`. Any help on how to bypass this nuance would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to posting on U&L!  Please always specify the version of the relevant software - in this case, whether it is Fedora 27 or Fedora 28.  It also wouldn't hurt to start with a little more history, e.g. was this installed from the main Fedora Workstation 28 "Live Image", or from a different source like the so-called "DVD Image", or maybe it's an upgrade from a previous version (in which case you might not remember the original source :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNOME login screen is provided by `gdm`.  You want `gdm` installed and enabled.  I think you have already installed it.  To enable it:

```
systemctl enable gdm
```

I just checked, and gdm is *not* listed as enabled by default in the "systemd-preset" file of Fedora Workstation.  I guess gdm must be handled specially by the installer.